# Remove "ID: string in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I want to remove `"ID:` in the string. So I tried

```
$eraser='';
modify="${origin/\"ID: /$eraser}";
```

How can i do that?
the string is like `"ID: 23409184074`

Comment: Actually your attempt should have had worked.  Could you elaborate how did it not work?

Comment: Both @devnull and @ fedorqui 's solution are worked. You can use either way.

Comment: @devnull I'm sorry I dont know the reason why it couldn't worked. It worked in other condition actually. And there is nothing special in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ origin=$'"ID: 23409184074'
$ echo "$origin"
"ID: 23409184074
$ echo "${origin//\"ID: /}"
23409184074
```

Answer (score 3):

You can delete from the space:

```
$ echo ${origin#* }
23409184074
```

Or make it more obvious:

```
$ echo ${origin#*ID: }
23409184074
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `"ID:` you can use `cut`.

`test='"ID: 23409184074'`

`echo "$test" | cut -d " " -f 2`

Comment: Why not `cut` on space?

Comment: @BroSlow  we can create cut on single character, and yes you are right we can write cut on  " "(Space).